# add image to push notification in oneSignal via rest api

Tags: onesignal

What is the key for adding image on push notification to IOS? I tried `imageUrl`, but does not seem to work. I used the UI from their website, and that worked.

```
{
      app_id: process.env.ONE_SIGNAL_ID,
      include_external_user_ids: d.emails,
      headings: { en: d.headings },
      subtitle: { en: d.subtitle },
      contents: { en: d.contents },
      app_url: "https://google.com",
      web_url: "https://google.com",
      ios_badgeType: "Increase",
      image_url:
        "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/01/21/01/46/architecture-3095716_960_720.jpg"
    },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some ) time here (two or three hours spent), I figure out what you should do. Basically, to add the image on the notification, you should add the `ios_attachments`, as the documentation mention

`ios_attachments : {"id": <link to your image>}`

However, if the link does not end with a valid image extension (i.e. jpg, png, and, etc), you should add `?filetype=file.jpg` at the end of the URL.

Thus, your final payload should be:

`ios_attachments : {"id": <link to your image>?filetype=file.jpg}`

For more information see this [troubleshooting post](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/troubleshooting-ios)

Answer (score 2):

Under `edit notificaiton` in the OneSignal website there is an `image` field where you can specify an image to be shown in the notification. When you fetch the notification through the rest api you can see this gets added under a property called `global_image`. Unfortunately setting the `global_image` property through the rest api does nothing, so I asked their support about it and got this response:

> Hello
>
> Our API doesn't have global_image but you can set it with the following properties based on the platforms targeted:
>
> https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference/push-channel-properties#attachments
>
> ios_attachments
>
> big_picture
>
> chrome_web_image

The `ios_attachment` property is a bit weird. It's particular about what keys it allows. I got it to work by just using `id` as the key like this: `ios_attachments: { id: 'https://example.com' },`

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure it out either.

Adds media attachments to notifications. Set as JSON object, key as a media id of your choice and the value as a valid local filename or URL. User must press and hold on the notification to view.

Do not set mutable_content to download attachments. The OneSignal SDK does this automatically

Example: {"id1": "<YOUR_IMAGE_URL>"}

Says on https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference/create-notification

Comment: But what does "valid local filename" mean anyway? How could OneSignal Server handle a local filename path through the JSON payload? Doesn't make any sense.